# ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed error while creating Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting below error while spinning up vm through Azure devops CD

> Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed" Message="User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Legal terms have not been accepted for this item on this subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deploy a resource which require additional legal and purchasing terms acceptance. You need identify the resource (normally it could be something non-Microsoft, like Oracle database or any network appliance) and use `Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms` before deployment (one time for any new non-standard Azure product).

AzureRm:

```bsh
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "microsoft-ads" -Product "windows-data-science-vm" -Name "windows2016" | Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.marketplaceordering/set-azurermmarketplaceterms?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Az:

```bsh
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "microsoft-ads" -Product "windows-data-science-vm" -Name "windows2016" | Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.marketplaceordering/set-azmarketplaceterms?view=azps-3.4.0

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I am using terraform task "apply" to spin up the vm, am not sure where i need to add this powershell or Az cli task

Comment: @daviroy in Azure CLI you have `az vm image terms`, as it should be done only once at a subscription level, I would like to suggest to create a subscription initialization script and do not put in terraform template (only if the goal of your template to deliver subscriptions)

Comment: Thank you, I believe it was more of enabling the programatic access to the resource, I think it also goes with quota limits if you are using MSDN or VS subscription, i did enable the flag and deployed it to the enterprise subscription thanks.

Comment: @daviroy you cannot use MSDN/VS subscription credits for third-party marketplace items which require specific payed licencing. Unfortunately, you need to autorize to charge your credit card

Answer (score 1):

It turn out to be enabling the programatic access. once its enabled make sure you are in right subscription unless its quota restricted...[Azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAM53.png)